# How to implement swipeable informational screens on app startup in .NET MAUI?

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm developing a mobile app using .NET MAUI and I want to implement swipeable informational screens that appear on startup to provide users with some introductory information about the app's purpose, features, etc. I've seen this feature in many apps, where users can swipe left or right to navigate through multiple screens before reaching the main app interface.

Would it be reasonable to implement these swipeable informational screens as ContentViews,PopUps or other methods?I am trying to find best practice of creating a series of swipeable screens that users can navigate through when they first launch the app. Any code examples or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: you could refer to this : https://www.xamboy.com/author/rendy-delrosariogmail-com/